# Find extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing components of eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: number-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{Z}^{d \times d}$ I need to find an algebraic number $a$ of minimal degree, such that all eigenvalues and eigenvector's coordinates of $\mathbf{A}$ belong to the extension $\mathbb{Q}(a)$.

I would start by finding characteristic polynomial $f$ of the matrix - then $\mathbb{Q}/f$ will contain all eigenvalues. Since all algebraic numbers are eigenvalues of some rational matrix, it's guaranteed that my $a$ is one of the roots of $f$. But how do I ensure that also the coordinates of eigenvectors lie in my extension field?

Or is there a better way to start, or any hints?

Comment: You need to get $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ to be a splitting field of $f$. That will ensure the eigenvalues are in there. The eigenvectors are going to be there necessarily since the solutions of a linear system of equations have coefficients in the same field as the coefficients of the matrix, and to find eigenvectors you solve $(A-\lambda I)v=0$.

Comment: Now, I don't think that $a$ is always going to be a root of $f$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the tip, I missed that fact completely. So this is just about finding the splitting field of char. polynomial, right?

Comment: Yes, and finding a [primitive element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem), $a$, for that extension. Notice the part about constructing such an element. There you see also an example. If the characteristic polynomial is $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$, then $a$ is not really any of its roots. One needs to take, for example, $a=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$.